# mysql error Call to undefined function mysqli_init() in windows

Tags: php, codeigniter, mysqli

I have installed apache server, php and  mysql in my remote system.(im not using xampp or wampp or any). I installed it separately. When I started working with codeigniter framework, it shows this error **Call to undefined function mysqli_init()** .I configured database in codeigniter and that is for sure.

Comment: if you come from php storm -> https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207033955-mysqli-connect-mysql-connect-error- or https://web.archive.org/web/20200805054537/https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207033955-mysqli-connect-mysql-connect-error-

Answer (score 1):

try this

Go to your `php.ini` and `remove comment` from `;extension=php_mysqli.dll`:

```
extension=php_mysqli.dll
```

If its not working than install

```
Try installing  php5-mysqlnd
```

If you cannot do it by hosting restrictions then just move to mysql driver (wont need to change other configurations or queries in CodeIgniter or anything else...)

like this (at your config file)

```
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql'; (you might have mysqli now)
```

Comment: i uncommented "extension=php_mysqli.dll" ...stilll no use...

Comment: so try other step @mohammedyaser

Comment: i found that in my phpinfo() file.... i couldnt see mysql config details... is that a problem.... and how to solve it?

Comment: mysqlnd is installed  already.. ...no use

Comment: after remove comment you restart the server?

Comment: i have done it ... still im stuck